# Resize image in css on a .jsp page

Tags: css, image, jsp

How do I make a large image smaller via CSS, with the image located on a JSP page?

I have tried different height, width, size and-so-on keywords, but nothing seems to work. 
It is possible though to move the image around, but can't figure out how to make it smaller.
The picture is saved in my project (it's not from an url).

**HTML:**

```
<div id="AUlogo"> 
   <img src="aarhus-university.png">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#AUlogo{ 
   margin-left: 23%; 
}
```

Hope my question is clear!

Comment: post relevant codes or a demo be better..

Comment: This is from the .jsp where the link to the image is.

<div id="AUlogo"> <img src="aarhus-university.png"></div>

This is the code I have so far in CSS (I've deleted my failed codes).

#AUlogo{

 margin-left: 23%;

}

@Amit

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nw40bhv8/)**

```
#AUlogo img {
    max-width:100px;
}
```

Specify the value in max-width as you need.. Hope this helps!!

Comment: thnx for answering, but it doesn't seem to work. The only thing that makes any change is this: `max-height: 50px; max-width: 50px;` but this only affect my footer which moves after the number of px.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
max-width: 90%;
```

and

```
max-height: 90%;
```

that should work, and when you did just height did you change the width or vice versa because if you dont change it with the same ratio as the img had it might mess up so try

```
height: 55px;
width: auto;
```

Comment: thnx for answering, but it doesn't seem to work. The only thing that makes any change is this:

`max-height: 50px;
max-width: 50px;`

but this only affect my footer which moves after the number of px.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to use CSS Resize Property

```
#AUlogo {
resize: both;
overflow: auto;
```

}

For resize Property you can use different values like

resize:both,horizontal,vertical,initial;

You can have any one of the property values to resize your image

Comment: Thanks Raj, but this doesn't seem to work either. I've tried your above suggestions. Maybe I'm doing it wrong. I've tried: `horizontal: 50px; vertical: 50px;` together and alone. Same with initial. Any idea why this is such a hassle?

Comment: Is your image stored in this path format under /WEB-INF/jsp.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand the question (I'm a novice in coding). But the image is store in the same folder as the jsp-file and the css-file. And to make myself clear - I need to get at larger picture smaller. Hope you have other ideas!

Comment: Might this help you, other than this I couldn't think anything                                                                                        <img:image src="%{image}" resize="true" height="25" refresh="false"/>

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either, it says `img:image` is an unknown tag. Thanks anyway!